# Do I need to create res folder manually in react-native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

If I'm working in a react-native project.

Do I have to create res folder with all the fonts, images and static content?
or
Does react-native compile and create res folder with all the assets for me?

React-native do this for both Android and iOS?

Thanks

Comment: Create a assets folder and copy all res into this folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add new fonts, you can add them to an /assets/fonts at your root directory. Them, you'll need to create an react-native.config.js to you project's root and add the following code:

```
module.exports = {
  assets:['./assets/fonts'],
}
```

And if you're talking about the native res folder, you don't need to create it manually.